# The scroll-margin-top property doesn't work when using a container with `overflow: hidden`

Tags: html, css, scroll-margin-top

I have a problem with the css property `scroll-margin-top` (adds offset when scrolling to element on page). It's not working in all the cases, in particular, this case: when the elements with `scroll-margin-top` are inside a container with `overflow: hidden`.

What can be the reason? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Not sure what extra 'detail' or 'clarity' this question needs.

Answer (score 31):

My problem was that the elements to which I had assigned the `scroll-margin-top` were sometimes in a container with `overflow: hidden`. As soon as the element is at the top and thus the `scroll-margin` protrudes from this container, the `scroll-margin` is also cut off by the `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: My god I spent a day debugging this same issue. Thanks for adding an answer here. And for the record, I think your question is clear or I wouldn't have found an answer!

Comment: Another reason why scroll-margin-top might not be working is if the element on which the scroll-margin-top is set has "display: inline". See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73120680/15471585

Comment: For me adding `tabindex="-1"` to the header solved the issue.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing this? (Thank you for spotting it, @skalta!)

Comment: @EliezerBerlin, perhaps you can look into using `overflow: clip` instead of `overflow: hidden` ? That might work for some situations, not entirely sure from the top of my head whether that also fixes the issue described here but it's worth a try?

Comment: I gave up and just `window.scroll() &  -100px` instead of `element.scrollIntoView() & scroll-margin-top`.

Comment: For me, it didn't work because the element, to which it had to scroll, was shown by js and then scrolled into view immediately. Seems like chrome didn't have enough time to render the element and scrolled to its old place. Scrolling after 500ms timeout helped me.

Comment: I had this issue with `overflow: auto;` on the parent.