# Why does overflow: hidden remove scroll margin top?

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-selectors, overflow

I have a container that has some animation and CSS with `overflow: hidden`.
When I apply `scroll-margin-top` to this container,
`overflow: hidden` removes it, and the effect is not visible.

I have a sticky header and when I click on a button, it should scroll to the container which should be below the header, but now the container is behind the header. I know `overflow: hidden` is causing the problem because when I use `scroll-margin-top` it works fine. How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212566/the-scroll-margin-top-property-is-sometimes-not-working

Comment: Have you tried padding the container instead of margining the element?

Comment: yes both didnt work

Answer (score 3):

You could use `scroll-margin-top` along-side `overflow: clip`, rather than `overflow:hidden`.

*Note: this will the effect of being unable to scroll contents overflowing the edge into view*

I believe this is because using `overflow: hidden` will create a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), while using `overflow: clip` will not.

For [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> Similar to `hidden`, the content is clipped to the element's padding box. The difference between `clip` and `hidden` is that the `clip` keyword also forbids all scrolling, including programmatic scrolling. The box is not a scroll container, and does not start a new formatting context. If you wish to start a new formatting context, you can use `display: flow-root` to do so.

Example:

```css
header {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

.blob {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  scroll-margin-top: 60px;
  overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob">
  <a href = "#here">Click me</a>
</div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob" id = "here">
  <p>Scroll to me</p>
  <p>Extra text</p>
  <p>Extra text</p>
  <p>Extra text</p>
  <p>Extra text</p>
</div>
<div class = "blob"><p>Div after scroll to me</p></div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
<div class = "blob"></div>
```